# getting error while updating record in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, oledb

in my form, when i modify data i'm getting error as 
 **'Command text was not set for the command object'**

I'm using oledb connection

Following us my code

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click    
Try
        sql = "select * from Employee"
        conn = New OleDbConnection(s)
        adapt = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn)
        ds = New DataSet

        usql = "Update Employee set enp_name=?, emp_addr=?, DOB=?, DOJ=?, emp_mob=?, emp_mail=? where ID=?"
        ucmd = New OleDbCommand(isql, conn)

        Dim date1 As Date
        date1 = DateTimePicker1.Value

        p = ucmd.Parameters.Add("@emp_name", OleDbType.Char)
        p.SourceColumn = "emp_name"
        p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current

        p = ucmd.Parameters.Add("@emp_addr", OleDbType.Char)
        p.SourceColumn = "emp_addr"
        p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current

        p = ucmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", OleDbType.DBDate)
        p.SourceColumn = "DOB"
        p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current

        p = ucmd.Parameters.Add("@DOJ", OleDbType.DBDate)
        p.SourceColumn = "DOJ"
        p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current

        p = ucmd.Parameters.Add("@emp_mob", OleDbType.Integer)
        p.SourceColumn = "emp_mob"
        p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current

        p = ucmd.Parameters.Add("@emp_mail", OleDbType.Char)
        p.SourceColumn = "emp_mail"
        p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current

        p = ucmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer)
        p.SourceColumn = "ID"
        p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current

        adapt.UpdateCommand = ucmd

        conn.Open()
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            adapt.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
            adapt.Fill(ds, "ABC")
            'conn.Close()
        End If

        tables = ds.Tables
        table = tables("ABC")
        rows = table.Rows
        cols = table.Columns

        row = rows.Find(TextBox1.Text)
        row.BeginEdit()
        row("ID") = TextBox1.Text
        row("emp_name") = TextBox2.Text
        row("emp_addr") = TextBox3.Text
        row("DOB") = DateTimePicker1.Text
        row("DOJ") = DateTimePicker2.Text
        row("emp_mob") = TextBox4.Text
        row("emp_mail") = TextBox5.Text
        row.EndEdit()
        'conn.Open()
        adapt.Update(ds, "ABC")** Getting error on this line 
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
  End Sub
```

But i'm not getting where i'm going wrong.... please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting `usql` to the `ucmd` anywhere.

```
ucmd.CommandText = usql;
```

Or rather, in your constuctor:

```
ucmd = New OleDbCommand(isql, conn)
```

`isql` should probably be `usql`. I am guessing there is an `isql` string field in the class if you are not getting compilation errors.